# Getting the parent div of element

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

This should be really simple but I'm having trouble with it. How do I get a parent div of a child element?

My HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <p id="myParagraph">Testing</p>
</div>
```

My JavaScript:

```
var pDoc = document.getElementById("myParagraph");
var parentDiv = ??????????
```

I would have thought `document.parent` or `parent.container` would work but I keep getting `not defined` errors. Note that the `pDoc` is defined, just not certain variables of it.

Any ideas?

P.S. I would prefer to avoid jQuery if possible.

Answer (score 448, accepted):

You're looking for [`parentNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317), which [`Element`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-745549614) inherits from [`Node`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1950641247):

```
parentDiv = pDoc.parentNode;
```

Handy References:

- [DOM2 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/) specification - well-supported by all major browsers
- [DOM2 HTML](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-HTML/) specification - bindings between the DOM and HTML
- [DOM3 Core](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/) specification - some updates, not all supported by all major browsers
- [HTML5 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/) - which now has the DOM/HTML bindings in it

Answer (score 56):

If you are looking for a particular type of element that is further away than the immediate parent, you can use a function that goes up the DOM until it finds one, or doesn't:

```
// Find first ancestor of el with tagName
// or undefined if not found
function upTo(el, tagName) {
  tagName = tagName.toLowerCase();

  while (el && el.parentNode) {
    el = el.parentNode;
    if (el.tagName && el.tagName.toLowerCase() == tagName) {
      return el;
    }
  }

  // Many DOM methods return null if they don't 
  // find the element they are searching for
  // It would be OK to omit the following and just
  // return undefined
  return null;
}
```

#### Edit 2021

[*Element.closest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) is part of the [DOM standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-dom-element-closest%E2%91%A0). It takes a selector as an argument and returns the first matching ancestor or null if there isn't one.

Comment: with jQuery : el.closest(tagName)

Comment: @Ullullu—let's see, 10,000 lines of library or a 10 line function? ;-)

Comment: @Ullullu's suggestion was really helpful, thanks.

Comment: @quant—you don't need jQuery for [*Element.closest*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest). :-)

Comment: @RobG cool, all the more reason to use it instead of writing your own. You should move that 2021 edit to the top of the your response as I think it's the right answer.

Answer (score 19):

The property `pDoc.parentElement` or `pDoc.parentNode` will get you the parent element.

Comment: But what's the difference?

Comment: The difference is well explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8685739/difference-between-dom-parentnode-and-parentelement

Answer (score 4):

`var parentDiv = pDoc.parentElement`

edit: this is sometimes `parentNode` in some cases.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/parentElement

Answer (score 1):

I had to do recently something similar, I used this snippet:

```js
const getNode = () =>
  for (let el = this.$el; el && el.parentNode; el = el.parentNode){
    if (/* insert your condition here */) return el;
  }
  return null
})
```

The function will returns the element that fulfills your condition. It was a CSS class on the element that I was looking for. If there isn't such element then it will return `null`

In case somebody would look for multiple elements **it only returns closest parent to the element** that you provided.

My example was:

`if (el.classList?.contains('o-modal')) return el;`

I used it in a vue component (this.$el) change that to your `document.getElementById` function and you're good to go. Hope it will be useful for some people ✌️

Answer (score 0):

This might help you.

```
ParentID = pDoc.offsetParent;
alert(ParentID.id);
```

Answer (score 0):

Knowing the parent of an element is useful when you are trying to position them out the "real-flow" of elements.

Below given code will output the id of parent of element whose id is provided. Can be used for misalignment diagnosis.

```
<!-- Patch of code to find parent -->
<p id="demo">Click the button </p>
<button onclick="parentFinder()">Find Parent</button>
<script>
function parentFinder()
{
    var x=document.getElementById("demo"); 
    var y=document.getElementById("*id of Element you want to know parent of*");
    x.innerHTML=y.parentNode.id;
}
</script>
<!-- Patch ends -->
```