# How do I find the classes assigned to an element in javascript (without jQuery)

Tags: javascript

I have hold of an "A" tag, and I would like to know what classes it's parents have got...so:

```
<div class="topone">
    <div class="middleone">
        <a href="#" class="thisone">tag</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

So I've got "thisone", but I want to know if there is a div above it somewhere that has the class of "topone"

...no jquery though, can't use jquery for this

Comment: obj.className will give you the attached class names.

Comment: This might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-parent-div-of-element-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className) property to access an element's class and [`.parentNode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode) to go to the parent element.

```
var classes = [];
for(var el = document.getElementById('#yourlink'); el; el = el.parentNode) {
    classes.push(el.className);
}
```

Note that `classes[0]` contains the classes of the element itself - but I'm sure it's no problem for you to modify the code accordingly if you do not want that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.parentNode` and `className` properties.

This is the way:

```
document.getElementById("MyElement").className
```

[Fiddler Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MAd2K/1/)

Comment: But where has "MyElement" come from?  This doesn't really answer the question

Answer (score 0):

You can write something like this

give your a tag an id, say bottomone

`var e = document.getElementById("bottomone").parentNode.className` will give you the class name as middle one.

and for the upper div, 
you can write

```
var e = document.getElementById("bottomone").parentNode.parentNode.className
```

Comment: but he is not sure where the element is

Answer (score 0):

```
var element =document.getElementById("topone");      
var liArray = element.childNodes;
      var i=0, item;
    if(element != null)
    {var status=0;
      while (item = liArray[i++]) {
        if (item.nodeType == 1) {
         if(item.className=="thisone"){status=1;}
        }
      }
    if(status==1){alert('it have parent node');}else{alert('it doen`t have parent node');}
    }else{alert('it doesn`t have parent node');}
```

i have tried at my level as per your requirement may it help you