# How to Get a Set of DIV IDs Without JQuery

Tags: javascript, class, html

I have a bunch of links that have ids that correspond with classes attached to other links. I am passing the link id through as a variable and then using that variable to find the other links by class with JavaScript. Here's a code example:

```
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){}
```

So far so good, I am able to do anything I want to those related links. However, now I want to get the ids of the divs in which those links reside. Is there any way to use JavaScript to find the div id of a link without using JQuery?

Before you ask, why not just use JQuery? I'm new at this and haven't learned JQuery yet. Furthermore, I would like to understand how to do things in JavaScript before I go trying to learn something else.

Comment: In principle, your element should have the `id` method on it for it to be called. Have you tried that?

Comment: It has the link's id. Is there a simple way of calling the div id as well?

Comment: Yes, you can walk up the dom tree.

Comment: the link is in the div you want so it's linkElement.parentNode.parentNode ...

Comment: If the link is inside a paragraph inside a div, then do I have to walk up two steps to get to my div? i.e. this.parentNode.parentNode

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access a parent element ID, you can use:

```
var elementId = elements[i].parentNode.id;
```

See here for more info: [Getting the parent div of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-parent-div-of-element-javascript)

To find the nearest DIV parent, you should be able to do something like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
    var parent = elements[i].parentNode;

    while (parent.localName != null && parent.localName.toLowerCase() != "div") {
        parent = parent.parentNode;
    }

    if (parent != null && parent.id != null) {
        var parentId = parent.id;

        alert(parentId);
    }
}
```

EDIT: Just added some null checking, in case a class is NOT contained in any DIV.

Here is the test I used:

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="asdf">
        <a href="#" class="blah">1</a>
        <a href="#" class="blah">2</a>
    </div>
    <div id="asdf2">
        <span>
            <a href="#" class="blah">3</a>
            <a href="#" class="blah">4</a>
        </span>
    </div>
    <!-- These two won't cause an alert since no DIV surrounds them -->
    <a href="#" class="blah">5</a>
    <a href="#" class="blah">6</a>
    <div id="asdf3">
        <span>
            <a href="#" class="blah">7</a>
            <a href="#" class="blah">8</a>
        </span>
    </div>

    <input type="button" onclick="run();return false;" value="Run" />

    <script>
    // This will cause 6 alerts: asdf, asdf, asdf2, asdf2, asdf3, asdf3
    function run() {
        var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("blah");
        for(var i=0; i<elements.length; i++){
            var parent = elements[i].parentNode;

            while (parent.localName != null && parent.localName.toLowerCase() != "div") {
                parent = parent.parentNode;
            }

            if (parent != null && parent.id != null) {
                var parentId = parent.id;

                alert(parentId);
            }
        }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if the div is not the parent?

Comment: The only thing I don't like about your answer is the fact I can only give you one upvote. Perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`element.parentNode.id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.parentNode) to get the parent element's `id` attribute.

Comment: what if the div is not the parent?

Comment: @Hogan: Then you restructure your HTML so that you don't have to run up and down the tree.