# change background color on parent element with css

Tags: css

How to make an effect with CSS when you hover over some div and after that parent container background color change like on the Codeschool website ?

Comment: You apply this in Javascript, see this [other post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-parent-div-of-element-javascript).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector

Comment: Indeed. After checking the source code, it's obvious that the class of the parent container changes when you hover on any of the divs. I don't think this can be achieved with pure CSS.