# how to access the parent tag using javascript from inside a child tag

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have the following code

```
<div id='div1'>
 <div onclick="f1(parent div tag)">
   hello
 </div>
</div>
```

I think my code is clear. Here I want to access the `<div>` with id `'div1'` (or say the id of it if available) to send it as a parameter to the JavaScript function `f1()`. How can I do It?

I am getting no reference for exactly this problem from anywhere else. Please help me out.

Comment: do you want to do it through pure javascript or jQuery will do?

Comment: Check here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: aren't you looking for this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/6856895/728610

Answer (score 1):

Use [`parentNode`](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html#ID-1060184317)

```
    alert(obj.parentNode.getAttribute('id'));
```

Refer **[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/SivaCharan/zzQ24/)**