# PHP: How to get the parent element of a button?

Tags: javascript, php, simple-html-dom

I have the following `form` and it has one of three `div`s (which have `id`s `div1`, `div2` and `div3`) as a child `div`:

```
<form id="myForm" method="GET" action="action.php">
  <div id="div1 or div2 or div3">...</div>
</form>
```

The `div` in the form has a `button`. I need to pass this `button`'s action listener (in JS) the `id` of the `div` it is a child of.

So is it possible to get the `div` which is the parent element of the `button` (or alternatively the `div` which is the child element of the `form`- it's the same `div` right?) using `simple_html_dom` parser or something else?

Comment: You can do: `$(myDiv).parent()` in jQuery. Or `myDiv.parentNode` in just JavaScript. Anyways this question already has an answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-parent-div-of-element-javascript

Comment: Is this about using  Simple HTML DOM in PHP, or JavaScript DOM?

Comment: @Scimonster I need to pass the `id` as an argument to the JS function when I am binding this action listener to the button, so obviously I need to get the `id` in PHP. So the question is about PHP!

Comment: @Zarah No you don't need to get the *id* in PHP, nor should you. JavaScript should be used for that. This being in a `<form>` means nothing when you are just getting the *id*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every element has a `parentNode` attribute. Access in javascript like so:

```
var element = document.getElementById('myElementID');
var parent = element.parentNode;
```

Answer (score 3):

You will need to assign an id to the button, then you can use Javascript to get the parent div:

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").parentNode;
```