# How to determine an element's language with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#the-lang-and-xml:lang-attributes), language is inherited from the nearest ancestor element which has `lang` set.  So how do I get the language of one of these descendents?

I'm setting the language with the `lang` attribute:

```
<div id="outer" lang="es">
    <div id="inner">¿Por qué?</div>
</div>
```

And trying to access it with the `lang` property:

```
alert(document.getElementById('outer').lang);
alert(document.getElementById('inner').lang);
```

I pretty quickly noticed that the `lang` property of the inner div isn't the inherited language (or it's not inheriting; no idea).  [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sv96aLh1/2/) demonstrates the behavior I'm seeing.

How can I determine an element's language with Javascript?  I'm really looking to take advantage of the inheritance of the `lang` attribute, as I also need this to work with screen-readers.

Comment: You'll have to traverse the DOM tree to find it.

Comment: Assuming the `lang` attribute is even set.

Comment: Just because a DOM element inherits behavior from an ancestor, does not mean it has the property set on itself.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sv96aLh1/3/

Answer (score 3):

From the very spec you linked to:

> To determine the language of a node, user agents must look at the
>   nearest ancestor element (including the element itself if the node is
>   an element) that has a `lang` attribute in the XML namespace set or is
>   an HTML element and has a `lang` in no namespace attribute set. That
>   attribute specifies the language of the node (regardless of its
>   value).

Inheriting from another element doesn't mean the attribute is set for the element itself. Therefore, your code must, as well, find the nearest parent with the `lang` attribute (if any exist). See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-parent-div-of-element-javascript) if that sounds problematic.

Comment: The OP needs to use [*hasAttribute*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-ElHasAttr) to determine if an element has the *lang* attribute. I guess `if (typeof element.getAttribute('lang') == 'string')` might do the job also.

Comment: I was really hoping that that *actual* user agent (the browser) would be able to do this for me.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that will return the value of the "lang" attribute of the nearest ancestor of any element, or undefined if none is found:

```javascript
function elementLang(el) {
  while (el) {
    if (el.hasAttribute('lang')) {
      return el.getAttribute('lang');
    }
    el = el.parentElement;
  }
}

// From your example jsFiddle...
elementLang(document.getElementById('inner')); // => "es"
elementLang(document.getElementById('outer')); // => "es"
elementLang(document.getElementById('output')); // => undefined
```

Comment: This would be a better solution if you made it iterative instead of recursive. Recursion is generally slow and there's no need to use it here.

Comment: So iteration is better than recursion?

Comment: Simple iteration is generally certainly faster, you simply can't always use it to achieve what you want in a reasonable manner.

Comment: What about tail recursion on tail-call-optimizing interpreters or compilers?

Comment: See the second half of my comment.

Comment: This will fail where the *lang* attribute is an empty string, e.g. `<div lang="">`. Better to use [*hasAttribute*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#ID-ElHasAttr).

Comment: @RobG: yes, good point; I've updated my code.  (Although I'm not sure if the empty string is more useful than null for conveying language info.)

Comment: @maerics—you could just return *undefined* if no element has the attribute (i.e. remove the final return statement). There is no need for the *else* block as the *if* block returns if true (the assignment statement is still required, just not in an else block).