# How get element by id with other context?

Tags: javascript, html

I want understand how can i get a element with id of 'takeme' in other context that is not the document, for example:

```
<div id="parent">
  <div id="takeme"></div>
</div>
```

I know that i can use:

```
document.getElementById('takeme');
```

being document the context, now i want know how can i get the takeme from the parent, without using `queryselectorall`, so i was trying to:

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.getElementById('takeme');
```

but of course didn't work.

Comment: ID is unique, you can get element by ID no matter where it is in the document.

Comment: i know, but i want understand how get elements with other context..

Comment: to get elements of an element you can use the various getElementsBy*  functions like `getElementsByTagName`,`getElementsByName`,`getElementsByClassName` etc

Comment: What's wrong with `querySelector(All)`?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-parent-div-of-element-javascript

Comment: An example of an "other context" would be most useful here.

Comment: Thanks @Mohamed-Yousef, i think you are the only one that understood that i want :P

Comment: You mean like `parent.childNodes[1].id`?

Comment: Sounds like you need querySelector with :scope, but that's future ;-)
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:scope#Browser_compatibility

Comment: @AmandaFerrari, the question Mohamed linked is asking how to get parent element, which is not at all what your question is asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getElementById` for an `HTMLElement` will not work because `getElementById` is only defined for **document**. There is a [**Document.getElementById**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) but there is not an `Element.getElementById`.

As commenters have mentioned, it is not needed from a *parent node* since the `id` should be unique to the `document`.

However, other methods like [**Element.getElementsByClassName**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) should work for a *different* context(`HTMLElement`)

```js
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var fromOtherContext = parent.getElementsByClassName('takeme');
console.log(fromOtherContext);

fromOtherContext = parent.getElementById('takeme');
console.log(fromOtherContext);//only works for document
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div class="takeme"></div>
  <div class="takeme"></div>
  <div class="takeme"></div>
  <div id="takeme"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

if you can put a class in addition to the ID

```
<div id="takeme" class="takeme"></div>
```

Then

```
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
var takeme = parent.getElementsByClassName('takeme');
```