# how to get parent div data-attribute javascript

Tags: javascript, pdf.js

I have a HTML structure like this :

```
<div class="page" data-page-number="29" data-page-label="18" data-loaded="true" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;">
   <div class="canvasWrapper" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;">
      <canvas id="page29" width="1632" height="2112" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;"></canvas>
   </div>
   <div class="textLayer" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;">
        some content
   </div>
</div>

    <div class="page" data-page-number="29" data-page-label="18" data-loaded="true" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;">
       <div class="canvasWrapper" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;">
          <canvas id="page29" width="1632" height="2112" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;"></canvas>
       </div>
       <div class="textLayer" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;">
            some content
       </div>
    </div>
```

I want to know that when I click on any `textLayer` class, I will get `data-page-number="x"` attribute from its parent `.page div`.

Only javascript solution required here.

This is basically PDF.js structure.

Comment: If you're trying to avoid jQuery, you can check the marked answer in this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-the-parent-div-of-element

Answer (score 4):

You could use *parentNode.dataset* to retrieve data attribute of parent node.

```js
var textLayer = document.querySelector('.textLayer');
textLayer.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  console.log('page number: ' + e.target.parentNode.dataset.pageNumber);
  console.log('label: ' + e.target.parentNode.dataset.pageLabel);
  console.log('loaded: ' + e.target.parentNode.dataset.loaded);
});
```

```html
<div class="page" data-page-number="29" data-page-label="18" data-loaded="true" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;">
  <div class="canvasWrapper" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;">
    <canvas id="page29" width="1632" height="2112" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;"></canvas>
  </div>
  <div class="textLayer" style="width: 816px; height: 1056px;">
    some content
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: querySelector only return the first matched element to receive all use querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".textLayer").on("click",function() {
   $(this).parent().attr("data-page-number");
});
```

pure js:

```
var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("textLayer");

var myFunction = function() {
    var attribute = this.parentElement.getAttribute("data-page-number");
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
}
```

// even shorter version

```
var elems = document.getElementsByClassName("textLayer").forEach(function(element){ 
    element.addEventListener('click', function(){
        var attribute = this.parentElement.getAttribute("data-page-number");
    }, false);
});
```

Comment: *"Unless another tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected"* (From the info that pops up when you hover over the "JavaScript" tag.) But if you're going to suggest a jQuery solution despite this you should at least say so explicitly in your answer.