# Get ID of parent input div with nested radio buttons for accessibility

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, accessibility

I have some custom radio buttons that are heavily nested. I would like for the child radio buttons to reference their parent in the label (for accessibility reasons). I am planning on using `aria-labelledby` to do this.

My biggest problem has been that the radio buttons are dynamically generated, so I need to be able to figure out what the parent id is.

Currently, the layout of the html looks like this:

```html
<div ...
  <input id="cat" name="level-parent" type="radio" value="cat" />
  <label for="cat" />
  <div>
    <div ...
    <div ...
     <div
     <div ...
       <input name="level-child-0" id=
leash" type="radio" value="leash">
       <label />
         <div ...
          <div ...
             <div ...
                <input name="level-child-1" id=
"blue" type="radio" value="blue">
                <label />
```

The inputs and labels are all generated by the same component that is mapped over.

```html
<input
          type="radio"
          name={`level-${level}`}
          value={choiceId}
          id={choiceId}
          aria-labelledby={}
        />
        <label htmlFor={choiceId} />
```

The choiceId and level are passed in as the radio buttons are being created.

I want each child to reference its parent when the label is read by the screenreader.

So for the `<input>` tag with `id="level-child-1"` it would say "leash, blue"
and for the `<input>` tag with `id="level-child-0"` it would say, "cat, leash"

Is there a way to grab the parent input id? 
I looked into using something like
`const parentInput = document.getElementById("label").parentNode.nodeName;`
but the problem is that I don't know the id of the parent. Can it go up the nodes until it find the id of the parent `input` component?

Here is a basic jsfiddle with a working nested radio button: http://jsfiddle.net/wgoLxanc/ so I at least have the concept figured out. The tricky thing is figuring out how to get the parent id.

Comment: when you dynamically generate it, can't you pass along the parent name as part of the ID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get an unknown ID of a parent element:

**Vanilla Javascript:**

One level up:

```
document.querySelector("YOUR-ELEMENT-SELECTOR").parentNode.id;
```

Two levels up:

```
document.querySelector("YOUR-ELEMENT-SELECTOR").parentNode.parentNode.id;
```

**jQuery:**

One level up:

```
$("YOUR-ELEMENT-SELECTOR").parent().attr("id");
```

Two levels up:

```
$("YOUR-ELEMENT-SELECTOR").parent().parent().attr("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

use data attribute in the radio button to save the parent ID.

see: [how to get parent div data-attribute javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44961886/how-to-get-parent-div-data-attribute-javascript)