# Can I select an HTML elements' nearest ancestor in Javascript (walking up the DOM)?

Tags: javascript, html

In the following code snippet, I want to capture the outermost element(li `.menu-item`) when the button is clicked.

Normally, I could use `document.querySelector(.menu-item)`, but in this case, these list items are dynamically added so multiple `li` elements exist with the `menu-item` class.

How do I get the closest `li` ancestor in order to extract the values of its children

```
<li class="menu-item">
    <div class="item">
        <p>Chicken Veg Roll</p>
        <img src="../../assets/img/menu/tasty-rolls.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="price">1350.00</p>
    <button class="order-btn" form="menu-item-form" type="submit">Add to Order</button>
</li>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the parent div of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-the-parent-div-of-element)

Comment: The awesome [jquery libray](https://jquery.com/) makes traversing the DOM trivial. The [closest](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) or [parents](https://api.jquery.com/parents/) methods could help you out here. **Don't** use jquery *just* for this, but evaluate if its features are worth the library overhead to your website.

Answer (score 1):

I make some assumptions about your case, but you can use [closest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest)

From MDN

> The Element.closest() method returns the closest ancestor of the
>   current element (or the current element itself) which matches the
>   selectors given in parameter. If there isn't such an ancestor, it
>   returns null.

Take a look to this example

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.order-btn');

buttons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', handleClick));

function handleClick(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    const li = this.closest('li');

    li.style.background = 'red';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <div class="item">
                <p>Chicken Veg Roll</p>
                <img src="../../assets/img/menu/tasty-rolls.jpg">
            </div>
            <p class="price">1350.00</p>
            <button class="order-btn" form="menu-item-form" type="submit">Add to Order</button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <div class="item">
                <p>Chicken Veg Roll</p>
                <img src="../../assets/img/menu/tasty-rolls.jpg">
            </div>
            <p class="price">1350.00</p>
            <button class="order-btn" form="menu-item-form" type="submit">Add to Order</button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <div class="item">
                <p>Chicken Veg Roll</p>
                <img src="../../assets/img/menu/tasty-rolls.jpg">
            </div>
            <p class="price">1350.00</p>
            <button class="order-btn" form="menu-item-form" type="submit">Add to Order</button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <div class="item">
                <p>Chicken Veg Roll</p>
                <img src="../../assets/img/menu/tasty-rolls.jpg">
            </div>
            <p class="price">1350.00</p>
            <button class="order-btn" form="menu-item-form" type="submit">Add to Order</button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <div class="item">
                <p>Chicken Veg Roll</p>
                <img src="../../assets/img/menu/tasty-rolls.jpg">
            </div>
            <p class="price">1350.00</p>
            <button class="order-btn" form="menu-item-form" type="submit">Add to Order</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

If the `li` elements are added dynamically you should probably implement [Event delegation](http://javascript.info/event-delegation)

Comment: Just note that `closest` won't work in IE without a polyfill.

Comment: Jon P is right about IE, the polyfill is here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest#Polyfill

Answer (score 0):

```js
function clickHandler(event) {
  alert(event.target.parentNode.tagName);
}
```

```html
<li> Test<br>
<button onclick="clickHandler(event)">Click me</button>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="menu-item">
    <div class="item">
        <p>Chicken Veg Roll</p>
        <img src="../../assets/img/menu/tasty-rolls.jpg">
    </div>
    <p class="price">1350.00</p>
    <button class="order-btn" form="menu-item-form" type="submit">Add to Order</button>
</li>   



 document.querySelector(".order-btn").addEventListener("click",function(e){
    console.log(e.target.parentElement);
 });
```