# Selecting a container DIV from a known link inside

Tags: javascript, dom

I am trying to work out how to select a container by a link contained within it. It looks something like this:

```html
<div>
  <p>Some text here</p>
  <a href="www.test.com">My Link</a>
</div>
```

I know the value of "My link". However, the div has no ID or class and is not contained within anything except the body.

How could I use javascript to select the div element so I can manipulate it? I've found ways to select the link using the DOM but not the outer div. There are many divs on the page, so I cannot just select div.

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: *"...and is not contained within anything except the body..."* It is in your example. It's contained in a `div`. Is that accurate re your real situation?

Comment: or possibly better target [Getting the parent div of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-the-parent-div-of-element)

Comment: @Liam - To me the question is more about finding the `a` element. (Wouldn't be surprised if there's a dupetarget for *that*, though, too...haven't immediately found one, but...)

Comment: yeah, not actually that clear now I re-read it. Hey hoooo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the only thing you know is that it's a `a` as a direct child of a `div` and it contains the text `My Link`, you can find it by finding all `div > a` elements and picking the first one that has that text:

```
const a = [...document.querySelectorAll("div > a")].find(a => a.innerText === "My Link");
```

*(That relies on the fact that `NodeList` become iterable a couple of years ago; you may need to [polyfill that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46929157/foreach-on-queryselectorall-not-working-in-recent-microsoft-browsers/46929259#46929259).)*

`a` will now be the first matching `a` element, or `null` if none matched.

From there, if you want that element's container, you can use [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) with a CSS selector. For instance:

```
const x = div.closest("CSS selector here");
```

...or just use `parentNode`/`parentElement` as needed.