# Get innerHTML for a parent parent in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have this code:

```
   <div class="places-item">
      <div class="places-item-img"></div>
      <div class="places-item-header">
         <h2>TEST</h2>
         <div class="places-item-header-add">ADD</div>
      </div>
   </div>
```

```
   document.querySelector('.places-item-header-add').addEventListener('click',function(){
      var getHTML = this.outerHTML;
      document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = getHTML
   });
```

The current code only displays div.places-item-header-add, and I want the entire div.places-item to be displayed. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit as to why you're trying to replace the entire HTML `body` with content from a single `div`?

Comment: It's just an example.

Comment: `this.parentElement.parentElement.outerHTML`

Comment: why not just replace .places-item-header-add with places-item?

Comment: or `this.closest('.places-item').outerHTML`

Comment: @YosefTukachinsky I love you! It works! Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the parent div of element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-the-parent-div-of-element)

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```
document.querySelector('.places-item-header-add').addEventListener('click',function(){
    document.querySelector('body').innerHTML = this.parentElement.parentElement.outerHTML;
});
```