# Replace content of div containing the link the user clicks on

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Using jquery (or vanilla javascript - not the library) how can I replace the content of a div when a user clicks a link that is contained in that div? For example

```
<div id="content">
   <a href="foo">bar</a>
</div>

$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
   var url = $(this).attr('href');
   $('#content').load(url + '.php');

   return false;
}
```

Obviously clicking on the link yields no results. Is there a clean way of doing this besides using React or something lol

Comment: Whats wrong with what you have?

Comment: Do you want to remove the link as well?

Comment: check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-the-parent-div-of-element), you can get the `parent node` then do the desired operation on it.

Comment: The right parenthesis of `on` closurer is missing. Maybe this Is the issue? Otherwise your script seems OK.