Making a variable element from existing element / querySelector doesn't accept Variables
Im trying to select a child div from an array with the variable x
This is only a sketch to illustrate what I'm trying to do:
var x= 0;
 trackN = document.querySelector( .track :nth-child(x))



But querySelector doesn't accept variables.
I don't have ids on these objects (i could add them if this is the only option) nor jquery...

I don't really understand what you're trying to do. Do you want to get the parent element of the elements querySelectorAll? This answer covers that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856871/getting-the-parent-div-of-element

you want var parentDiv = tracks[x]

@Wryte No, I have multiple child elements and all have the same id. I want a variable that changes on a button click and thus changes what child gets displayed.

querySelector() accepts a string so you should be able to pass a variable...
document.querySelector('.track :nth-child('+x+')');


Oh really? May have been a mistake on selecting the right child then? Why have y written + x + btw?

x is a number... your variable! Its value will join up with the rest of the string.

Oh! So this was just a styling problem then. Thank you!

Fare thee well…

Fare ther well!
